# Structure for a Multi Module Angular Application

Tags: angularjs, module

We need to develop an application which has to bootstrap different modules based on the URL Params. Like APP1 if url has http:domain.com?appName=APP1, APP2 if url has http:domain.com?appName=APP2, but the domain.com is same. How can we implement this and what can be the best folder structure.

**Background**

We are using Angular JS, Node(API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definitely https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modularity

`- core/**/*.js // all common parts
- app1/..
- - ......
- app2
- - app.js // module efinition
- - config.js // defined routes/states (ui-router)
- - other_module/
- - - app.js // other_module definition
- - - config.js // defined routes/states (ui-router) for other_module
- - - controllers/*.js || *.spec.js // file with spec.js are for tests
- - - directives/*.js
- - - services/*.js 
- - - partials/*.html // for templates
- - other_module2/...`

Bind it with require.js, write tests (for example `foo-ctrl.js` and test for this keep in the same directory with spec.js extension `foo-ctrl.spec.js`)